# elasticsearch - Terms filter with multiple condition

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, querydsl

I want to achieve searching for multiple values with 2 or more conditions in one hit to ES.

`For Eg, "customer" index has 2 fields userid and order`. I used below query to search results matching both fields.

```
`{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "userid": [
                "1","2"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "order": [
                 "A","B"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

the result matched documents satisfying all combinations(like `1&A, 1&B, 2&A, 2&B`). But i need the results matching only in the order sent(like `1&A, 2&B`). Can we achieve this with Terms Filter or any other alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use nested `"and"`s and `"or"`s:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "or": {
                    "filters": [
                        { "and": [
                            { "term": { "userid": { "value": "1" } } },
                            { "term": { "order": { "value": "A" } } }
                        ]},
                        { "and": [
                            { "term": { "userid": { "value": "2" } } },
                            { "term": { "order": { "value": "B" } } }
                        ]}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea..this works :). btw, do we have any limit on the "and" queries inside "filters"? Sometimes i need to retrieve for 300 to 500 users at one go?. Also what is the performance impact?

Comment: this is not valid any more

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you'd need to put the fields "userid" and "order" inside a **nested** field.  something like this kind of mapping:

```
{
    "index1" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "type1" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "iAmNested" : {
                        "type" : "nested",
                        "properties" : {
                            "userid" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            },
                            "order" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would then query using an nested filter, information can be found here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html