# Elasticsearch: how to write bool query that will contain multiple conditions on the same token?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field with tokenizer that splits by dots.
on search, the following value  `aaa.bbb` will be splitted to two terms `aaa` and `bbb`.

My question is how to write bool query that will contain multiple conditions on the same term?

For example, i want to get all docs where its field contains a term that matches a fuzzy search for `gmail` but also the same term must not contain `gamil`.

Here are some examples of what i want to achieve:

- `bmail` // MATCH: since its matches fuzzy search and is not `gamil`
- `gamil.bmail` // MATCH: since the term `bmail` matches fuzzy search and is not `gamil`
- `gamil` // NO MATCH: since its matches fuzzy search and but equals `gamil`

NOTE: the following query does NOT appear to be working since it looks as if one term matches one condition and the second term matches the other, it will be considered a hit.

```
{
  ...
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "fuzzy": {
              "my_field": {
                "value": "gmail",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "max_expansions": 2100000000
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "my_field",
                    "query": "*gamil*",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Did you try the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614805/elasticsearch-terms-filter-with-multiple-condition

Comment: @D.C can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @D.C could you use a token filter to remove the terms that should not match ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html#analyzer-anatomy-token-filters

Comment: @RonSerruya if i understand correctly, the suggestion there was to join two fields into ```nested``` one, in my case i have only one filed being tokenized to multiple tokens

Comment: @ESCoder can you please be more specific? Im not sure what else is missing, i posted an example for the query and provided expected results for it in the question

Comment: @cylon86 the issue with that approach is that i don't want to remove the term entirely, i just what to have the ability to add conditions on it on a specific part of the query. also im not sure i can add it dynamically, from the example i saw its a configuration on the analyzer and i want to configure it per query

Comment: @D.C can you please share few sample documents and your index mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) by executing fuzzy (or any other) query, and then programatically filter the results by the returned highlight object.

[span queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html) might also be a good option if you don't need regular expression or you can make sure you don't exceed the boolean query limit.
(see more details in the provided link)